# Non-deterministic behavior with expect script task kill

Tags: bash, ssh, tcl, expect

I am trying the snippet below to dump some logs for exactly X seconds before terminating. What I am expecting is for this to terminate and output the "Log dump complete" line 100% of the time.

Instead, it only happens some of the time, and other times, it hangs with the "root#" shell stdin prompt, which is not actually interactive and I can only Ctrl+C out of. What is going wrong here?

```
spawn bash -c "ssh $username@$hostname"
expect  "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)" {
            send "yes\r"
    } "Enter passphrase for key " {
        } "password:" {
                send "$password\r"
        } "#" {
                send "./some_script > ~/recording.log & sleep $DURATION; kill $!\r"
                expect "Terminated" {
                    puts stdout "\nLog dump complete"
                    flush stdout
                }
        }
```

Comment: In the cases where it fails, do you see `Terminated` in the output?

Comment: I do not, but it hangs with the user input prompt before `$DURATION` passes

Comment: If `some_script` finishes before the timeout, you'll get a prompt, and without the "Terminated" the expect script won't know to stop waiting. Can you make it also accept `root#`?

Comment: If you run your scripot with `expect -d`, the verbose debugging output will allow you to see where your pattern are or are not matching.

Comment: Having it accept `root#` works, thanks! I want to identify the source of inconsistency though, to have a more complete answer. In my case, the script is guaranteed to keep running forever until killing so that's not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Expect has a default timeout of 10 seconds, so if DURATION is longer than that it will timeout when waiting for "Terminated".  You can set a longer timeout, e.g. 60 seconds with the command `set timeout 60`.

See https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html for full details.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am setting timeout earlier in the script so this is not the issue

Comment: @Layman, setting it to what?

Comment: `set timeout 600000`